# xpages anonymous access looses login credentials

Tags: xpages

I have a xpages app. with anonymous access.
For some parts to access I need to login in (I use roles to hide the admin parts of the application)
When I login via a url like http://myapp.com/app.nsf?opendatabase&login I can enter my credentials and I am authenticated to the server and app.
When I navigate to some pages I notice it starts to work with anonymous access again.
So for some reason the server drops the credentials.

Any idea?

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Hi  what type of authentication is used? basic or form ?

Comment: Basic authentication.

Comment: Which URLs are you opening when it looks like the server is loosing the credentials? Please also check the Requests send over the wire with the browser dev tolls (Hit F12). Is the Cookie/Token included in these request?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off anonymous access for the application that holds the XPages and then turn on the public access setting for those XPages that require anonymous access.

Comment: It is not that simple. The app is a portal showing data from other Notes Database. So the anonymous user needs almost all pages except the admin pages.

Comment: Put those in a different database then or set the acl for the XPage itself for those pages to be the higher access and the user will have to be logged in to use them.

Comment: Well... the portal needs to be access by anonymous users. The data that the anonymous user is accessing is a temporary database with temporary documents for security reasons.  So that works. But the config of the portal needs a login. So in the "old days" I log in by adding &login at the url. And it works for a few pages and then it looses the credentials

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Safari issue. 
After cleaning my history and cache it works..

Thanks all for the help.

Regards,
Peter